# > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

Tags: node.js

Estou a executar `sudo npm install websocket` no meu Mac com nodejs mas me ocasiona este erro, como corrigir?

```
npm install websocket
-
> websocket@1.0.19 install /Users/Vinicius/node_modules/websocket
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
websocket@1.0.19 node_modules/websocket
├── nan@1.8.4
├── typedarray-to-buffer@3.0.3 (is-typedarray@1.0.0)
└── debug@2.1.3 (ms@0.7.0)
```

Comment: QUal é a versão de node.js que estás a usar? (faz `node -v` para te dar a versão)

Comment: @Sergio  v0.12.7 foi o que me resultou

Comment: Na documentação no github refere que suporta as versões 0.8 e 0.10. Talvez seja esse o problema.

Comment: @Sergio eu baixei a versão 0.8 e me retorna agora na hora de instalar, este grande error https://jsfiddle.net/L43gtw6b/

Answer (score 0):

É necessário ter o [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) como dependência.

Primeiro você deve verificar qual a versão do **Python** que está instalado na sua máquina, recomenda-se a versão **v2.7** para uma maior compatibilidade, pois as versões **v3.x.x** não são suportadas.

Depois é necessário instalar um compilador **C/C++** globalmente no seu Mac, para isso use a seguinte biblioteca [GCC Installer for OSX](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)

Apoś isso instale o node-gyp

**$ npm install -g node-gyp**

Agora é só instalar o websockets

**$ npm install websocket**

Espero ter ajudado, abraços e boa sorte!

Comment: Python? Fiz isso e o erro persiste, uso node na versão v0.12.7 e ao executar `npm install -g node-gyp` ele me retorna esses erros https://jsfiddle.net/eLgdjfvp/

Comment: e ao executar a mesma função com `sudo` na frente ele me retorna isto https://jsfiddle.net/eLgdjfvp/1/ e o `sudo npm install websocket` me retorna a mesma coisa

Comment: Sim Python! Na própria documentação do node-gyp tem essa observação e pede o GCC como dependência também. Outra alternativa seria usar uma versão anterior estável do [node.js v0.10.36](http://blog.nodejs.org/2015/01/26/node-v0-10-36-stable/) e tentar fazer a instalação, pois pode ser que está havendo um problema de compatibilidade entre o node-gyp e a versão v0.12.7 do node.js